# API to Purchase Domains For G-Suite, Programatically

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I am not able to find any G-Suite SDK or G-Suite REST API that I can call to purchase Domains for G-Suite linked sites.

I want to be able to create G-Suite-linked public domains programmatically.

While G-Suite allows purchasing domains through UI and while GoDaddy has listed REST APIs to purchase domains here: https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains I am not able to find an API published by G-Suite. 
Clarifying: This is not about creating a G-suite site but a public domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hen you buy a domain from G Suite, this means the G Suite sign up flow for customers that don't have a domain yet at the time of the registration, the domain is purchased from any of the three different partners, GoDaddy(GoDaddy API is involved), Enom(Enom API is involved) and Google Domain(the purchase may use back end directly there is no information if an API is used). This is because G Suite is not Domain registrar you can't buy domains from them directly they just don't offer that service thus there is not G Suite API for this.

Google Domains, on the other hand, is Domain registrar and host service, dedicated to the domain business, There is an API for Google Domains that you can use to so customers can buy a domain without leaving your web site, however, not necessarily the API will fit the needs that you may have, however, is the only API available at the time, see https://developers.google.com/domains/widget/.

Comment: Will wait for a few more days for other responses if any and then mark this as accepted. This is indeed a great find. Wondering why didn't my searches return this result. Thank you.